# How to load more than one autocomplete in framework7?

Tags: javascript, html-framework-7

I'm learning framework7. My problem is that:
In my view i have to include more autocomplete input, but i can't load all.

I'm using the Dropdown With Ajax-Data + Typeahead
https://framework7.io/docs/autocomplete.html

my html

```
<li class="item-content item-input">
<div class="item-inner">
    <div class="item-title item-label">Language1</div>
    <div class="item-input-wrap">
        <input id="autocomplete-dropdown-ajax-typeahead" type="text" placeholder="" name="language1">
    </div>
</div>
</li>
<li class="item-content item-input">
<div class="item-inner">
    <div class="item-title item-label">Language2</div>
    <div class="item-input-wrap">
        <input id="autocomplete-dropdown-ajax-typeahead" type="text" placeholder="" name="language2">
    </div>
</div>
</li>

<li class="item-content item-input">
<div class="item-inner">
    <div class="item-title item-label">Language3</div>
    <div class="item-input-wrap">
        <input id="autocomplete-dropdown-ajax-typeahead" type="text" placeholder="" name="language3">
    </div>
</div>
</li>
```

I put the js code in js/pages/languages/languages.js and i included it in the index.html in this way

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/pages/languages/languages.js"></script>
```

the languages.js

```
const languages1 = () => {
 var autocompleteDropdownAjaxTypeahead = app.autocomplete.create({
inputEl: '#autocomplete-dropdown-ajax-typeahead',
openIn: 'dropdown',
preloader: true, //enable preloader
/* If we set valueProperty to "id" then input value on select will be set according to this property */
valueProperty: 'name', //object's "value" property name
textProperty: 'name', //object's "text" property name
//limit: 20, //limit to 20 results
typeahead: true,
dropdownPlaceholderText: 'Type...',
source: function (query, render) {
  var autocomplete = this;
  var results = [];
  if (query.length === 0) {
    render(results);
    return;
  }
  // Show Preloader
  autocomplete.preloaderShow();

// Do Ajax request to Autocomplete data
app.request({
  url: 'js/data/languages/languages1.json',
  method: 'GET',
  dataType: 'json',
  //send "query" to server. Useful in case you generate response dynamically
  data: {
    query: query,
  },
  success: function (data) {
    // Find matched items
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
      if (data[i].name.toLowerCase().indexOf(query.toLowerCase()) === 0) results.push(data[i]);
    }
    // Hide Preoloader
    autocomplete.preloaderHide();
    // Render items by passing array with result items
    render(results);
  }
});
}});}

const languages2 = () => {

var autocompleteDropdownAjaxTypeahead = app.autocomplete.create({
inputEl: '#autocomplete-dropdown-ajax-typeahead',
openIn: 'dropdown',
preloader: true, //enable preloader
/* If we set valueProperty to "id" then input value on 
select will be set according to this property */
valueProperty: 'name', //object's "value" property name
textProperty: 'name', //object's "text" property name
limit: 20, //limit to 20 results
typeahead: true,
dropdownPlaceholderText: 'Type...',
source: function (query, render) {
 var autocomplete = this;
 var results = [];
if (query.length === 0) {
  render(results);
  return;
}
// Show Preloader
autocomplete.preloaderShow();

// Do Ajax request to Autocomplete data
app.request({
  url: 'js/data/languages/languages2.json',
  method: 'GET',
  dataType: 'json',
  //send "query" to server. Useful in case you generate response dynamically
  data: {
    query: query,
  },
  success: function (data) {
    // Find matched items
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
      if (data[i].name.toLowerCase().indexOf(query.toLowerCase()) === 0) results.push(data[i]);
    }
    // Hide Preoloader
    autocomplete.preloaderHide();
    // Render items by passing array with result items
    render(results);
  }
});
}});}

const languages3 = () => {

var autocompleteDropdownAjaxTypeahead = app.autocomplete.create({
inputEl: '#autocomplete-dropdown-ajax-typeahead',
openIn: 'dropdown',
preloader: true, //enable preloader
/* If we set valueProperty to "id" then input value 
on select will be set according to this property */
valueProperty: 'name', //object's "value" property name
textProperty: 'name', //object's "text" property name
limit: 20, //limit to 20 results
typeahead: true,
dropdownPlaceholderText: 'Type...',
source: function (query, render) {
  var autocomplete = this;
  var results = [];
  if (query.length === 0) {
    render(results);
    return;
  }
// Show Preloader
autocomplete.preloaderShow();

// Do Ajax request to Autocomplete data
app.request({
  url: 'js/data/languages/languages3.json',
  method: 'GET',
  dataType: 'json',
  //send "query" to server. Useful in case you generate response dynamically
  data: {
    query: query,
  },
  success: function (data) {
    // Find matched items
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
      if (data[i].name.toLowerCase().indexOf(query.toLowerCase()) === 0) results.push(data[i]);
    }
    // Hide Preoloader
    autocomplete.preloaderHide();
    // Render items by passing array with result items
    render(results);
  }
});
}});}
```

and i call the autocomplete elements in my-app.js

```
 {
    name: '',
    path: '',
    url: '',
    routes: [

      {
        name: 'languages',
        path: 'languages/',
        url: './pages/languages/languages.html',
        on: {
            pageInit: languages1,
                      languages2,
                      languages3

            }
      }]
 },
```

but it doesn't work. It works only one if i comment on the other two.

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'r main issue on ID selector, You have 3 IDs with name `autocomplete-dropdown-ajax-typeahead`, ID selector most be refer to only one item to work truthly, to fix that you can do this:

```
<li class="item-content item-input">
<div class="item-inner">
    <div class="item-title item-label">Language1</div>
    <div class="item-input-wrap">
        <input id="autocomplete-dropdown-ajax-typeahead-1" type="text" placeholder="" name="language1">
    </div>
</div>
</li>
<li class="item-content item-input">
<div class="item-inner">
    <div class="item-title item-label">Language2</div>
    <div class="item-input-wrap">
        <input id="autocomplete-dropdown-ajax-typeahead-2" type="text" placeholder="" name="language2">
    </div>
</div>
</li>

<li class="item-content item-input">
<div class="item-inner">
    <div class="item-title item-label">Language3</div>
    <div class="item-input-wrap">
        <input id="autocomplete-dropdown-ajax-typeahead-3" type="text" placeholder="" name="language3">
    </div>
</div>
</li>
```

Also you need to edit languages.js to refer each El to your target id:

```
const languages1 = () => {
 var autocompleteDropdownAjaxTypeahead = app.autocomplete.create({
inputEl: '#autocomplete-dropdown-ajax-typeahead-1',...

const languages2 = () => {
     var autocompleteDropdownAjaxTypeahead = app.autocomplete.create({
    inputEl: '#autocomplete-dropdown-ajax-typeahead-2',...
```

Async route:

```
routes: [
  {
    name: 'languages',
    path: 'languages/',            
    async(routeTo, routeFrom, resolve, reject) {
      // You can put you condition to make sure all languages are fill                  then resolve url
      // For test reason you can create setInterval function thats keep             check value, when success remove interval and go to resolve
      var checkTimer = setInterval(function(){ 
        if(languages1 && languages2 && languages3){
          clearInterval(checkTimer);
          resolve({
            url: './pages/languages/languages.html',
          });
        }
      }, 500);        
    }
  }]
```

You can look for direct example to resolve your case without more option:

[Online Example Code](http://jsfiddle.net/5prjqm34/)

Comment: Thank you for your help. I changed the id, but it still not work. It works only the first autocomplete-dropdown-ajax-typeahead-1. Because i call it before the others two in my-app-json: languages1, languages2, languages3. If i chage the orderd like languages2,languages1,languages3.. languages2 works and the others not

Comment: Welcome Mate, I think now this issue since page is load before the other request is complete ... so that you can use (Async Route) ... https://framework7.io/docs/routes.html#async-route

Comment: Can you write me an example?

Comment: I edit my answer mate, and I add example for async route :D

Comment: Sorry, I didn't see it :D but it's strange, because in this way both do not work

Comment: LOL, NP, can you please check if theres any error i console? also please console.log(lang1, lang2, lang3)...inside setInterval ...to check langs value

Comment: it write:    () => {


  var autocompleteDropdownAjaxTypeahead = app.autocomplete.create({
  inputEl: '#autocomplete-dropdown-ajax-typeahead-1',
  openIn: 'dropdown',
  preloader: true, //enable preloader
  /* If we set val…

  my-app.js:116 () 

=> {

  var autocompleteDropdownAjaxTypeahead = app.autocomplete.create({
  inputEl: '#autocomplete-dropdown-ajax-typeahead-2',
  openIn: 'dropdown',
  preloader: true, //enable preloader
  /* If we set va…

Comment: I write a real example for you without more option mate...check fiddle link in my answer..keep note I change name to title...since I use online api test...Also Theres note...created variable name need to be also to be 1,2, 3 .. since in autocompleteDropdownAjaxTypeahead is override autocompleteDropdownAjaxTypeahead...etc

Comment: Thank you for your patience! I solved the issue in this way:  on: {
       pageInit: function(){
           languages1(); languages2(); languages3();
           
          }
         }